# C# Console app - Bing Maps - how to save output

Tags: c#, console-application, bing-maps, bitmapimage, writeablebitmap

I can get a URI from Bing Maps but when I try to save the resulting file (eg, a .jpg) it is empty (eg, 1 x 1 size). I've got it working fine in a WPF app with event handling but how do I do it with a console app?

Here's the code that works with WPF but the same code fails in a console app - I think it must be because the file is saved in an event handler and (far as I know) you can't do that in a console app.

```
public void vSaveBitmapImage(string sURI, // created with Bing Maps GeocodeServices
  string sLocFname)
{
  // save file name so event handler knows it
  this.sFname = sLocFname;

  try
  {
    BitmapImage bmpImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(sURI, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    // setup event handler - file is saved just fine here
    bmpImage.DownloadCompleted += vImage_DownloadCompleted;
  }
  catch (SystemException sex)
  {
    string s = sex.Message;
  }
}

/// <summary>
/// handle the event that an image download has completed
/// </summary>
private void vImage_DownloadCompleted(object sender,
  EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();

    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create((BitmapImage)sender));

    using (var filestream = new FileStream(this.sFname, FileMode.Create))
      encoder.Save(filestream);
  }
  catch (SystemException sex)
  {
    string s = sex.Message;
  }
}
```

Comment: Chuckled immaturely at that you called your system exception "sex".

Comment: yeah, sorry about that - came across that one years ago and been using it ever since ;)

Comment: Now that you've had a chuckle tell me how to save a bing map in a console app before I pull out all my hair!

Answer (score 0):

For a console application, it may be simpler to download and save the file synchronously, e.g. with [WebClient.DownloadFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile.aspx).

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile( sURI, sLocFname );
```

I'm not sure what is going wrong with your event-based code.

My first guess is that the application drops out of Main() and exits before the background download completes.  In that case, you may need to block the main thread until your `vImage_DownloadCompleted` event is completed.

Comment: Thanks! WebClient - nice. Btw, I tried "hanging" main() with a Console.Readline() to wait for the event, with no luck. 'gonna have to research console apps and event handling.